# SwfObject and Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, swfobject

I have a strange problem with SwfObject and Google Chrome browser. In my webpage is 
form where user can input link of the Youtube video. After form submit video must appear on the same page in div, near the form. In other browsers it works good, but in Chrome I have to refresh page manually if I want to see video. I do not understand what's the problem...

My SwfObject:

```
<object width="330" height="267"><param name="movie" value="someUrlVar" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="someUrlVar" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="330" height="267"></embed>
</object>
```

I put it on a div:

```
<div>objectVar</div>
```

Any hints about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with other code places in the site. Now everything is ok.